# Django PostgreSQL db_index on JSONField to query by exact key

Tags: django, postgresql, indexing, jsonb

I have a Place model:

```
class Place(models.Model):

    ... some not interesting fields

    distances = models.JSONField()
```

In JSONField (distances) stores something like:

```
{
    '1': 10
    '2': 20
    '3': 30
    '4': 40
    ...
    '1000': 10000
}
```

where key is 'id' of some Location model, and value - 'time in road' to this Location from this Place

If website user selects Location, I show Places in order from closest to further to selected Location:

```
places = Place.objects.all().order_by(
    RawSQL('distances->%s', (str(selected_location_id),))
)
```

And everything is cool, except performance.

But, PostgreSQL support indexing for JSONB fields (which use Django for JSONField):

**GIN**, **btree** and **hash**

1. What differences between them? Which is suitable for my example?
2. Does django support db_index on JSONField? If yes, how to specify which    index to use?

Big thx for help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine what type of index to use in Postgres?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326625/how-to-determine-what-type-of-index-to-use-in-postgres)

Comment: A great deal of your question is answered by the linked question. The rest of it sounds like a situation where you shouldn't use jsonb

Answer (score 1):

To index a particular key in json, create a raw sql migration:

1. Run `./manage.py makemigrations --empty yourApp` where `yourApp` is the app of the model you want to change indexes for.
2. Edit the migration i.e.

```
operations = [
    migrations.RunSQL("CREATE INDEX idx_name ON your_table((json_field->>'json_key'));")
]
```

Where `idx_name` is the name of the index, `your_table` is your table, `json_field` is your JSONField, and `json_key` in this case is the key you want to index.

Not sure if there is a native wrapper for this kind of thing in django, I looked and could not find but this should do it. You might want to put a note that this index is created via this migration in your model meta as well. Cheers!